# App Engine JDO Persistent class migrate from com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key to Long

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I've been working to get an app that runs on GAE to support other platforms like a single instance of a Jetty Server.

A Persistent JDO class with a primary key defined like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "false")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Foo implements Bar {


    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    protected Key key;
```

The key is a com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

Short of doing a data migration, is it possible to somehow convert this field to a Long or something that's supported in other platforms like mySQL and not needing to use an app-engine library?

Answer (score 0):

ok looks like it's possible to just convert it to a string and i'm good to go.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "false")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class EntityStore implements Entity {


    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    protected String key;
```